# Nodes have additional keys when using neo4j-javascript driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j

I'm slowly migrating my backend over to use the new javascript drivers for neo4j 3.0.3 over the bolt protocol but objects returned contain 3 properties:

```js
{
  identity: {},
  keys: [],
  properties: {
    foo: 'bar',
    fooo: 'baar'
  }
}
```

I was using a simple rest client before and it would just return the properties, which is what I wanted. How do I get it do that using the javascript drivers and omit this nested structure?

Comment: You can't. This is now the standard API for all language drivers.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopheWillemsen I will bare that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've since discovered that NEO4J has a `properties()` method which extracts all the properties from the node.

```
MATCH (n:User)
WHERE n.name = 'bob'
RETURN properties(n)
```